# Trying to keep data from moving down in grouped report

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I'm trying to create a report which shows a list of all companies and all jobs awarded for that company. I have the company name at the top of the group with a total at the bottom-inside of the group. I also have address information for the companies which I am trying to keep directly under the company name. The address data keeps moving down. How can I keep the data up directly under the company name.

As you can see from the image above. I want the address information moved up directly below the company name. Below is what my design view looks like.

Comment: Where are you putting the address information? Can you show examples?

Comment: @WEI_DBA please see the edited post above which includes screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to add a new line in an expression.

`=Fields!Company_Name.Value & vbcrlf & Fields!Address.Value & vbcrlf & Fields!Province.Value`

Answer (score 1):

If you can do a screenshot of the report in design that would help.  My guess is you have to work with the "insert row outside group above" while having the company row group selected.  Then put your address in the right row.

The other way I have seen is to put the address and company and text all together in one output line in the SQL and use Char(10) + Char(13) to put in the line breaks.

Comment: Please see the screenshots above that I just added. I'm thinking I will have do join the fields on the SQL server side perhaps?

Comment: It looks like you need to add a parent group by company first.  Then you are headed down the right path.  I would Google that but here is a great video that helps...  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=keBOCdMfelU

Comment: I currently do have a parent group added on company. The issue is when the data for each company grows, it moves the address data down too far. Is there an expression or property I can use on the Tablix to keep specific rows or cells or something from growing?

Comment: Oh, I see. It is the tender description and file reference number that push that row down.  Maybe merge company cells, then make room for those cells to show all they need on one row.  Smaller fonts help with that too.

Comment: See below for the answer. I had to add vbcrlf after each expression to get my data to line up correctly. Thanks for your help!